# Async function returns fine, but array becomes empty

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, asynchronous

I just learned about Async functions in a question I posted earlier and I needed to incorporate another one. I am reading a list of entries from Firebase, return a list of them, and assigning them to an array.

Now the problem is, when I return the array to the calling function, the array is now empty and I am not sure why.

This is how I am collecting the Firebase entries (works fine):

```
func getListItems(uid: String, completion: (list: Array<String>?) -> Void) {
    let ref = Firebase(url: getFirebaseURL() + "/" + uid)
    var taskList = [String]()

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {
            taskList.append(rest.value as! String)
        }
        completion(list: taskList)
    })
}
```

And this is how I am calling that function and trying to assign it to a local array so I can add those items to a TableView:

```
// Retrieve database items
let uid = def.valueForKey("uid") as! String
getListItems(uid) {
    (result) in
    self.taskListItems = result!
    //print(result) // This prints out an array filled with my data
}
print(taskListItems) // This prints an empty array
```

If I do `print(result)` it spits out a perfect array, but not when I print the local array I am trying to use. I have defined `taskListItems` as: `var taskListItems = [String]()`

I have also tried using `.append` which did not work either so I'm really lost on what is going on.

Comment: You have a race condition. The code in the closure is happening on a separate thread. By the time you print your array the closure code has not completed.

Comment: This has been dealt with many, many times on Stack Overflow, so please search before asking. See, for example, my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33699235/341994

Comment: @matt Yes, i learned **about** async functions, I obviously did not **learn** them, which is why I am asking here

Comment: @ryantxr Thanks. I thought that having it completed in the 'getItemList' function would have actually been fully completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the line where you do `print(taskListItems)` is called before `print(result)` in your block. This is because the HTTP request is asynchronous, and executes the code inside the block after it's finished (which is after `print(taskListItems)` is called). What you should do is have your code where you use the results inside the block.

Comment: Thanks! I am using a tableview to display all of the entries so I think I need to have it accessable from multiple places. What I did was just update my tableview and then appeared.