# How to get result from closure function

Tags: ios, function, swift3, closures, swift4

citylist has value only in this closure, outside of closure value is nil, why? even after this function finish, citylist value is nil.. Help Please.. How to get this result from closure

---

```
func setData(){
    let conn = ApiConnection()
    conn.get_cities{ result in
        self.cityList = result!
    }
    print(self.cityList)
}
```

Comment: `get_cities` works asynchronously (the closure is executed later). Move the `print` line in the closure

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699156/how-do-i-return-coordinates-after-forward-geocoding

Comment: Yes i know.. even after the end of the this function... cityList value is nil..Here's the problem

Comment: Please learn to understand the pattern of asynchronous data processing. If you need to *return* something you have to add an asynchronous completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
 func setData(){
    let conn = ApiConnection()
    conn.get_cities{ result in
        self.cityList = result!
        print(self.cityList)
     }
  }
```

As `conn.get_citie` runs in a separate background thread than the main so flow goes to print line which is not yet have a value , so prints nil / empty --- but when print method inside the completion of the function it prints the actual data returned from the API call