# How to block anything from happening until a func has been completed?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I have been looking around and have not found a way to prevent anything from happening until a function is completed. Basically, the events which are below the function are occurring before the function is. Let me show you the code and the console output.

Code:

```
if locationSwitch.isOn == true {
            let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)&result_type=locality&key=AIzaSyDI-ZacHyPbLchRhkoaUTDokwj--z_a_jk"
            loadUrl(url: url) { optionalLocation in
                guard let nonOptionalLocation = optionalLocation else {
                    // Location was nil; Handle error case here
                    return
                }
                // Do something with your location here, like setting UI or something
                print("Optional Location: \(optionalLocation)")
                print("nonOptional Location: \(nonOptionalLocation)")
                cityState = nonOptionalLocation
                print("cityState: \(cityState)")
                print("Within Func")
            }
            print("Within If")
        } else {
            lat = 0.0
            lng = 0.0
            cityState = ""
        }
        print("After If")
        print("cityState Outside If Statement: \(cityState)")
        CoreDataHandler.savePhotoObject(locationCoordinateLatitude: lat, locationCoordinateLongitude: lng, locationLocality: cityState, dateCreated: date, discription: discriptionBox.text!, photo: selectedImageData!)
    }
```

Console Output:

```
Before If
Within If
After If
cityState Outside If Statement:
Optional Location: Optional("San Francisco, CA, USA")
nonOptional Location: San Francisco, CA, USA
cityState: San Francisco, CA, USA
Within Func
```

As you can see

```
Optional Location: Optional("San Francisco, CA, USA")
nonOptional Location: San Francisco, CA, USA
cityState: San Francisco, CA, USA
Within Func
```

should come before

```
Within If
```

I believe this is happening because the `loadUrl` function takes so long to complete that the code goes over it and completes the code under it then `loadUrl` completes and then is printed after everything else. This wouldn't be a problem except for the variable that is set equal to `nonOptionalLocation` is called after the `loadUrl` function is completed and because `loadUrl` ends up finishing after the rest of the code the variable that should be equal to `nonOptionalLocation` is actually equal to `""`.

Does anybody know how this could be completed right now I think that I need to block anything from happening until after `loadUrl` is completed, but if you know of another way to do this please share. Thank You.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33699235/341994

Comment: @PatrickHaertel It is absolutely related.

Comment: @vadian and matt please forgive my last comment. I do agree with you that it is related. I had skimmed the post only after I had solved the issue in my code thanks to vadian, and I must have skimmed to fast because I clearly missed the point. Please forgive me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loadUrl` works asynchronously, just put the code to be executed after returning the data **into** the completion block

```
if locationSwitch.isOn == true {
    loadUrl(url: url) { optionalLocation in
        guard let nonOptionalLocation = optionalLocation else {
            // Location was nil; Handle error case here
            return
        }
        // Do something with your location here, like setting UI or something
        print("Optional Location: \(optionalLocation)")
        print("nonOptional Location: \(nonOptionalLocation)")
        cityState = nonOptionalLocation
        print("cityState: \(cityState)")
        print("Within Func")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            CoreDataHandler.savePhotoObject(locationCoordinateLatitude: lat, locationCoordinateLongitude: lng, locationLocality: cityState, dateCreated: date, discription: discriptionBox.text!, photo: selectedImageData!)
        }
    }
} else {
    CoreDataHandler.savePhotoObject(locationCoordinateLatitude: 0.0, locationCoordinateLongitude: 0.0, locationLocality: "", dateCreated: date, discription: discriptionBox.text!, photo: selectedImageData!)
}
```

Comment: That cannot be done because I get this error: UITextField.text must be used from main thread only

Comment: vadian's answer is correct. You fundamentally do not understand how async completion handlers work. The whole point of the completion handler is that you should put your code that you want to run after the URL loads inside the completion handler (inside the curly braces..) if that completion handler is called on a background thread then you need to wrap any code that calls UIKit functions in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()` (as shown in vadian's answer)

Comment: I would have to put that in the else statement as well, correct?

Comment: No, you have to write the `CoreDataHandler.savePhotoObject(` line twice. I updated the answer again. But do you really want to save an quasi empty photo object?

Comment: @vadian Yeah. I need to save it empty because when a continue button is pressed another view is loaded where all of this data is loaded and if, for example, the `cityState == ""` then a label is hidden; however, if `cityState != ""` the label is not hidden. A problem that I am having now that I wasn't having before is that when the continue button is pressed, the data that is loaded on the next page is the data from a previous time. To get the right data you have to press continue, then press back (dismisses current view controller), then press continue again. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question. Please ask a new one.

Comment: @vadian it doesn't matter I was able to figure it out myself. Actually, it was the same error that was happening in this post. Basically the segue was being performed before the data could be saved, so under the `CoreDataHandler` I added `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "modalPresentationImage", sender: nil)` and I created a segue that wasn't attached to any button in the storyboard and gave it the identifier `"modalPresentationImage"`. This seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used DispatchQueue.main.sync{}, It may be stuck in your UI for a while that is not good but if you have no issue with this then you can try this.

```
if locationSwitch.isOn{

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {

            let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(location.latitude),(location.longitude)&result_type=locality&key=AIzaSyDI-ZacHyPbLchRhkoaUTDokwj--z_a_jk"

            loadUrl(url: url) { optionalLocation in
                guard let nonOptionalLocation = optionalLocation else {
                    return
                }

                print("Optional Location: \(optionalLocation)")
                print("nonOptional Location: \(nonOptionalLocation)")
                cityState = nonOptionalLocation
                print("cityState: \(cityState)")
                print("Within Func")
            }
        }
        print("Within If")
    } else {
        lat = 0.0
        lng = 0.0
        cityState = ""
    }
    print("After If")
    print("cityState Outside If Statement: \(cityState)")
    CoreDataHandler.savePhotoObject(locationCoordinateLatitude: lat, locationCoordinateLongitude: lng, locationLocality: cityState, dateCreated: date, discription: discriptionBox.text!, photo: selectedImageData!)
```